# Delete a line containing string in text file using php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$myFile = "myfile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'rt');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
$aDoor = $_GET['idno'];
echo $aDoor;
$theData = preg_replace('/\n?.*$aDoor.*$/m', '', $theData);

fwrite($fh, $theData);
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
?>
```

preg_replace('/\n?.*SOMETEXT.*$/m', '', $theData); it is working

Now how to use $aDoor string

Comment: no $aDoor is a string getting form previous php file

Answer (score 0):

use `unset()` function in php

Example

```
 unset($aDoor);
```

Then write the contents...

Comment: preg_replace('/\n?.*SOMETEXT.*$/m', '', $theData); it is working 

Now how to use $aDoor string

Comment: preg_replace('/\n?.SOMETEXT.$/m', '', $theData); it is working

Now how to use $aDoor string

Comment: how to use var string in preg_replace

Comment: $string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
This is an example of pre_replace()